# Definition of Martyr in Islam

Tags: hadith, hell, definitions, martyr

Whether a non-Muslim who dies for his country is called as Martyr?
For example:
A non-Muslim soldier who saves the people of country from terrorist attack and loose his life for the sake of country or people or good deed? Whether he will be considered as Martyr according to Islam?

If yes, then will he face the fire of Hell as he died as non-Muslim?

Comment: "Died for his country"?!?! Different countries wage wars against each other for different purposes, these purposes can be unlawful such as waging war in the purpose of looting another countries resources, just dying for someone country as a puppet may not make you martyr! however dying in "Sabeel Allah" does as long as the intention is there, for example protecting your family or other believers! not sure what's the case if your a non Muslim!

Comment: You will need to add more context to your question, for me it's very unclear what exactly you are asking. Add an example.

Comment: Updated my question. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: I'm confused!! Your question in the title says "In Islam", but the example you gave is for a non-Muslim?? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked same question to Mufti Munawwar Husain Sahab, Director of [Tawheed Centre](http://www.tawheedcentre.org/?utm_source=stackexchange). 
His reply was as below:
To be called as martyr it is mandatory to have Iman . So if a non-muslim dies saving the people of his country he will not be called a martyr according to Islam as he didn't fulfill the condition of Iman.

To get more clarification one can directly [contact](http://www.tawheedcentre.org/enquiry-form/?utm_source=stackexchange) Mufti Munawwar Husain.

Comment: @Shoaib Chikate : Please mark te answer correct if you are satisfied with same.

Comment: its also nice to show some of the resources that Imam used!